# dynamic php website, $_GET folder variable

Tags: php

I'm having an error here, how to load the specific folder as user selected in home.php?

My code:

```
<?php
        $pass = array('home','main','result');
        $lang = array('eng','thai');
            if (in_array(@$_GET['page'], $pass, $lang)) { 
                include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './jeff/page/' . $_GET['$lang'] . '/' . $_GET['page'] . '.php'); 
        } 
                elseif (!isset($_GET['page'])) { 
                include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './jeff/page/home.php'); 
            } else { 
       include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './jeff/page/error.php'); 
         } 
    ?>
```

My home.php

```
<A href="Thai">Thai</a><br />
<a href="Eng">Eng</a>
```

inside my page folder, I have another two folder which is `eng` and `thai`.

I want the code to load eng or thai value to `$_GET['lang'] when user select the language from home.php

For example, if the user select `Eng` the page will load main.php from eng folder and if the user select `Thai` the page will load main.php from thai folder.

May I know where did I get wrong and the code is not working?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're going for, but did you mean `if (in_array(@$_GET['page'], $pass) && in_array($_GET['lang'], $lang))`?

Comment: Your using in_array wrong, `in_array (mixed $needle, array $haystack [,bool $strict = FALSE ])` http://us2.php.net/in_array

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Read it again, then look at what you're passing to `in_array()`. The PHP reference is [here](http://nz2.php.net/in_array)

Comment: added the correct question, may I know how to load the specific folder of content base on user select on home.php?

Comment: @Clive I changed my question as the previous I wrote wrongly, mind help me take a look?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit cleaner - don't think you need to further check for an error, since you know you can always default to home.php. Also, don't need the third in_array() param:

```
<?php

$baseUrl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './jeff/page/';
$pass = array('home','main','result');
$lang = array('eng','thai');

if(!isset($_GET['page']) && !isset($_GET['lang'])){
    include ($baseUrl . 'home.php'); 
} else {
    if (in_array($_GET['lang'], $lang)) { 
        $baseUrl .= $_GET['lang']; 
    }       
    if (in_array($_GET['page'], $pass)) { 
        $baseUrl .= $_GET['page']; 
    } 
    include ($baseUrl . '.php'); 
}
```

Comment: but my html code how to it I write it to load the specific folder? my current one is not working

Comment: Including files by user input without checking its existence.

Comment: @Sbls means? please advise

Comment: I think he means that allowing users to input include paths is quite dangerous, and he's right. Even though my code may answer your problem, I think the way you're going about things is not the best solution. By allowing a user to enter a path, essentially, he could include and hack into your server by accessing files outside the web root.